# Script with Pyspark and pure python being executed in EMR

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, pyspark, cluster-computing, amazon-emr

I'm executing Script with Pyspark and pure python in EMR. The ideia is that part of the ETL is in Pyspark because it's basically a lot of data. Later on I used the toPandas method to convert and be able to execute the pure python code that uses these databases as inputs. I notice that the pure python execution is slower than what I tested locally. Looked in the YARN timeline server that the container executing this code only has 896 of memory allocated (and obviously 1 core). Is there a way to make it faster?

I tried using spark configs to maximize resource allocation. Nothing worked. Maybe I'm using the wrong configs or not using it properly.